# POST rest API method using https fails

Tags: python, rest, api

I get an error when I try to invoke rest-api POST method with the URL. URL for POST is : "https://localhost/rest/v1/admin/ds" .

When I invoked the rest api it gave the following error:

> raise HTTPError('{} Client Error: {}'.format(response.status_code, response.reason), response=response)
>
> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found

Code :

---

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import json
from ocm import connection, configure_command_line_parser 
"""connectivity python file """
  def create_datasources(target,file_location):
        if not os.path.exists(file_location):
             raise IOError('Failed to find json file at', file_location)

         json_file=open(file_location, 'rb')
         print("json file is \n\n\n",json_file)
         result=oci.post('https://localhost/rest/v1/admin/ds', files=json_file)
         return (result)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     options = configure_command_line_parser().parse_args()
     url, user, password = options.url, options.user, options.password
     file_location = "C:\Python34\Scripts\ds.txt"

     with connection(url, user, password) as target:

            result = create_datasources(target, file_location)
            print(result)**
```

---

Note:
1. The code doesnot throw any syntax error.

2. The server to which I want to post data is logged in.
3. I am able to access the URL and see the information of the datasources that are already created.( I want to create one new datasource using rest API call ).
4. The file is in the JSON format. The contents are as per requirement.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be with the code you posted; the problem is that your web server is complaining that `/rest/v1/admin/ds` is not a known URL.  How is this data being served?

Comment: why do you think the response should be different than 404?

Comment: Hi John, The GET method works fine and I am able to get the data using the same URL. Only the POST method throws an error. I am pretty new to Python and can u please explain what goes wrong or what should be done?